# Moving WooCommerce Password Field on Checkout

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to MOVE the PASSWORD field on the CHECKOUT page to be next to Phone. I've searched and searched and I have managed to get this together and yet, it does not work.

The password field (renamed into Confirm Phone Number) is still at the bottom right of the checkout and somehow (?) there is another field on top under the phone.

[image]

Here is the code that I am using:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'change_order_of_checkout_fields', 15, 1 );
function change_order_of_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    $billing_order = array(
        'billing_first_name',
        'billing_last_name',
        'billing_email',
        'billing_phone',
        'account_password',
        'billing_company',
        'billing_address_1',
        'billing_address_2',
        'billing_postcode',
        'billing_city',
        'billing_state',
        'billing_country'
    );

    $current_count = 0;
    $priority = 10;

    foreach($billing_order as $field_name){
        $current_count++;
        $fields['billing'][$field_name]['priority'] = $current_count * $priority;
    }

    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['class'] = array('form-row-wide');
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['class'] = array('form-row-first');

    $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['class'] = array('form-row-first');
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['class'] = array('form-row-last');

    if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) == 'no' ) {
        $fields['account']['account_password'] = array(
            'type'          => 'password',
            'label'         => __( 'Confirm Phone Number', 'woocommerce' ),
            'placeholder'   => _x( 'Confirm Phone Number', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce' ),
            'required'      => true,
            'class'         => array('form-row-last')
        );
    }

    return $fields;
}


function woocommerce_password_filter() {
return 0; }
add_filter( 'woocommerce_min_password_strength', 'woocommerce_password_filter', 10 );


add_filter('password_hint', 'change_woocommerce_password_hint_text');
function change_woocommerce_password_hint_text($hint) {
  return "Thank you for conforming your phone number. This will be your password.";
}
```

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Comment: I have updated the question and added a picture. Hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: Anyone with an idea on how to make this work?